# How Elastic Search Cluster Set Up can be done on a Single Machine?

Tags: elasticsearch, deployment, cluster-computing

On my single machine on different disks I want to set up Elastic Search Cluster cluster node set up,how this can be achieved?

Comment: single machine on different disks? what does that mean? Are you saying you want multi-node cluster on a single machine? Is it for test purpose or production? useful reference - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-have-multiple-nodes-on-same-machine-with-elasticsearch-2-0-0/35578/13

Comment: @prayagupd.. on one machine I have multiple disks,my basic use case is if one them crashes 2nd can be used ,how I can achieve this? Then I came across ES Cluster in which second machine is used if one is down,so can I meet my objective using ES Cluster on single machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a elastic cluster. One master and a client and two data nodes.
Data nodes will be use Disk 1 and disk 2. Master and client nodes will be use something disk.
e.g:

1. elastic-master-node - PORT: 9020

Config:

node.name: es-master-01

node.master: true

node.ingest: false

node.data: false

http.enabled: false

path.data: /data/es-master-01

---

2. elastic-client-node - PORT: 9021

Config:

node.name: es-client-01

node.master: false

node.ingest: true

node.data: false

http.enabled: true

path.data: /data/es-client-01

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost:9300"]

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3

---

3. elastic-data-node - PORT: 9022

Config:

node.name: es-data-01

node.master: false

node.ingest: false

node.data: true

http.enabled: false

path.data: /data/es-data-01 ( DISK 1 )

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost:9300"]

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3

---

4. elastic-data-node - PORT: 9023
   Config:

node.name: es-data-02

node.master: false

node.ingest: false

node.data: true

http.enabled: false

path.data: /data/es-data-02 ( DISK 2 )

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost:9300"]

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3

Comment: For this I'll need mutilple ES configs.How I'll maintain that?

Comment: I have only one node as server.

Comment: Basically how to get multiple data points in one elastic search instance?

Comment: How to do you install the elasticsearch? 
e.g.:
I downloaded the elasticsearch and I made 4 directory ( es-master-01 , es-client, es-data-01, es-data-02 )

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html

You need to 4 node ( 4 directory, 4 config ..etc ) on the server.

Comment: Other solution:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html
You need to start the ES with config path parameter and you will be one ES directory and 4 config

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I hadn't tried this as my requirement was changed.Now I have to 2 nodes master master cluster Set-up. Thanks for help. :)